# Representing image readed by HTML5 FileReader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm uploading an image with a help of html5 filereader like this:

```
$scope.add = function(){
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

    r.onloadend = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
        console.log(data);
        $http.post(myUrl,{
            data: e.target.result,
            withCredentials: true,
        }).success(function (dat) {
            $scope.image = dat; // If you want to render the image after successfully uploading in your db
        });
    }

    r.readAsBinaryString(f)
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

But when I'm getting my picture back I don't know how to represent it. It isn't 64based string, which is read from `e.target.result` and I don't even know what `FileReader` uses. How can I represent this data?

Comment: what shows when you hover over your "dat" in your success object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller:

```
$scope.add = function(){
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
        r = new FileReader();

    r.onload = function(e){
        var data = e.target.result;
        console.log(data);
        $http.post(myUrl,{
            data: data,
            withCredentials: true,
        }).success(function () {
            $scope.image = data;
        });
    };

    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

View:

```
<img class="thumb" ng-src="{{image}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = "";

  // Create a new image.
  var img = new Image();
  // Set the img src property using the data URL.
  img.src = reader.result;

  // Add the image to the page.
  fileDisplayArea.appendChild(img);
}
```

Here is an example on how to use filereader to display an image

Comment: I prefer to do it with a help of angular directives, but thank you!